# How can i change metallic property of materials in a collection?

Tags: python, materials, shader-nodes

I find everywhere but there are no ways to access properties of materials in a collection, please help!

This is my base code:

```
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes:
        mat.metallic = 0
        continue
    for n in bpy.data.collections['124'].all_objects:
        #for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
            n.inputs["Specular"].default_value = 0
            n.inputs["Metallic"].default_value = 0
        else:
            print("bbbbbbbbbb")
```

I want to change the metallic properties of all object in collection "124" to 0 (the "Sphere" object)
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you give more details and screenshots of what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i modified the thread, can you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy


for object in bpy.data.collections['124'].all_objects:
    if object.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    for material in object.data.materials:
        if not material.use_nodes:
            continue

        for node in material.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                node.inputs["Metallic"].default_value = 0
                node.inputs["Specular"].default_value = 0
```

Comment: thanks, it worked